# urllib.request.urlopen TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

What am I doing wrong?

```
from urllib import request

def get_page(page):
    page = request.urlopen(page).read()
    return page

def get_next_target(page):
    start_link = page.find("<a href=")
    if(start_link == -1):
        return None
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote+1)
    url = page[start_quote+1:end_quote]
    print(url)
    return(url,end_quote)

def print_all_links(page):
    while True:
        url, endpos = get_next_target(page)
        if url:
            print(url)
            page = page[endpos:]
        else:
            break

page = get_page('https://xkcd.com/')
print(page)
get_next_target(page)
#print_all_links(page)
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xkcdscrape.py", line 29, in <module>
    get_next_target(page)
  File "./xkcdscrape.py", line 8, in get_next_target
    start_link = page.find("<a href=")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type of [read](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse.read) is `bytes`.  In your `get_page` function call [decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) to convert the bytes to a string.

```
def get_page(page):
    page = request.urlopen(page).read()
    return page.decode('utf-8')
```

You can read more about using `urllib` to fetch internet resource [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html). However [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) provides a simpler interface for such tasks.

It's also simpler to do web scraping using a library like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).